# Unable to vagrant up - how to set "providers"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I am trying run vagrant but after `vagrant up` error appears:

```
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

I installed before VirtualBox version 4.3.26 r989888 and Linux Ubuntu (64 bit)

After:
`vagrant box add precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box`

`==> box: Adding box 'precise32' (v0) for provider:
    box: Downloading: http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 1425k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'precise32' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!`

when I list
`vagrant box list`

```
lucid32   (virtualbox, 0)
precise32 (virtualbox, 0)
```

**What is wrong with "provider"**

`vagrant package --base vagrant-ubuntu64`

```
Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.

Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.
```

How to help him detect VirtualBox ?

Comment: The error message says Vagrant cannot access VBoxManage. Open your terminal type VBoxManage and check if it is recognized. If not then find the VBox location on your file system (where you will see VBoxManage) and add it to your PATH as instructed by Vagrant message. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 55):

Quick note - Vagrant 1.8.4 and Virtualbox 5.1.X aren't compatible on MacOS 10.11 (can't set a provider).

Virtualbox 5.0.10 works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for reporting! Was struggling for a while now.

Comment: Dude! Life saver, this should be the answer for OSx 10.11

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately vagrant up doesn't report this. For the records: vagrant package --base trusty
Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported by this version of Vagrant. Please install one of
the supported versions listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.0

Comment: FYI: Vagrant 1.8.5 should work with 5.1 (just checked Vagrant's changelog on Github), but is unreleased as of today.

Comment: Awesome - Just installed 5.0.14 on MacOS 10.12 without error.  I could run the stock vagrant box and an install of VirtualHostX 7 without error :)

Comment: Verified this fixes it, here is the bug: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7578

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 16.06. Had to donwload Vagant 1.8.5 from their site as the apt package version was only at 1.8.1.

Comment: Had similar issue with Vagrant 1.9.1 with older versions of virtual box. I installed virtual box 5.1 and it works perfect.

Comment: As comment above, I had this issue... updating to Virtualbox 5.1.26 and Vagrant 1.9 works on OSX 10.11 El Capitan :)

Answer (score 23):

I was able to fix this simply by installing the latest version of Vagrant (as of this writing 1.7.4).

Comment: I was on Vagrant 1.7.2 and VirtualBox 5.0.8 and upgrading to Vagrant 1.7.4 fixed this for me too

Comment: Actually 1.7.4 only made partial progress for me.  What ultimately fixed it was removing the .vagrant folder from the project directory.

Comment: Thanks! -- updating to Vagrant 1.8.1 with VirtualBox 5.0.10 worked for me as well. Did not have to remove the .vagrant file. Now somebody tell us why. :)

Answer (score 22):

simply try to bring vagrant up and specify provider you want to use:

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

As per screenshot below, it will tell you the reason why specified provider is not working. In my case, it was an unsupported version of VirtualBox 5.2. I had to downgrade it to v 5.1

[image]

Comment: This worked for me.  I was trying to use VirtualBox v6.1.0 which was not supported by Vagrant.  Thanks, Clayton

Answer (score 8):

There seems to have been an [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3852) reported since VirtualBox 4.3.12:

VirtualBox automatically create the following environment variable `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH`

However, vagrant (if you look for the `base.rb` file) uses the variable `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH`

So you can
- update the variable name `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH` and change it to `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH`
- create a new variable name `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH` with the same value as `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH`

*Reminder* on windows go to `My Computer (right click) --> Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> Environment Variables` and look for the variable you need to manage

Comment: Thank you for providing the most in depth and insightful answer.  So many of the responses on this particular question on other threads of this same topic provide a generic "this worked for me" without an explanation of what the root cause is, and plausible resolutions.

Answer (score 5):

ok so I was having the same issue with windows, vagrant and virtualbox and did this.

1. click on "This PC" / "My Computer" on windows desktop
2. Select "Properties"
3. Go to "Advanced" tab
4. Click "Environment Variables..." at the bottom
5. Under System Variables click "New..."
6. Set "Variable name" to "VBOX_INSTALL_PATH"
7. Set "Variable value" to "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
8. Select "OK" and close all the other settings windows

credit goes to here:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3852

I am assuming that there is a Environment Variable ( or PATH for linux users I think :P) that needs the "path" to the virtualbox executable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running macOS 10.12 and installed vagrant 5.1 using homebrew.

I got the same error as the OP and fixed it by downloading the latest version of VirtualBox (v5.1.6).

N.B. This version is labeled amd64 on the [download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), this is just the name of the 64 bit standard and will install fine on Intel macs.

Answer (score 2):

I had installed Virtualbox `6.1` and Vagrant `2.2.6` and got this error on a Mac. I had to revert Virtualbox to `6.0` and then `vagrant up` worked with `ubuntu/trusty64`. See @Serge Voloshenko's answer above for how to discover if it's a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the Version problems either it can be problem from vagrant or from Virtual box to connect

Try this : vagrant up --provider virtualbox

Above command will help if the version of virtual box is compatible or not and it will also suggest which are the current linkable versions of Virtual box

Currently : 4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3,5.0,5.1,5.2 are the versions of virtual box that are working

By the way, If you are worrying about version of Vagrant, I have tried current version : 2.0.3